# Can LED strips be used as photodetectors?

Tags: led, led-strip, photodiode, detection

As I did not find any photodiode/PD strips available, I am wondering if it would be possible to use LED strips as photodetectors. And if yes, which type of LED strip could be used for that purpose?

My idea would be to detect an object moving between two aligned strips and to determine the objects position. The distance between the two strips would be between a few centimeters and about 100 centimeters. The resolution needed would be about 5-10 centimeters, which is the reason I thought about using LED strips in the first place.

Strip: o----o----o----o----o
Object ->
Strip: o----o----o----o----o

Other suggestions would also be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LEDs can be used as photodetectors, but LED strips lack one essential feature: if the LEDs were used as detectors, the output of each individual LED could not be read. Only the power supply pins are accessible. Individually addressable LEDs wouldn't work either, as the chip is made to send current into the LEDs, not the other way around.

I'd recommend rolling your own. jlcpcb.com has a pretty cheap assembly service if you use their parts library. So I checked and it contains some pretty cheap IR sensors, CdS light sensors, etc. You'd need to multiplex the outputs into your microcontroller ADC with some analog switches.

Another, maybe simpler way to do this would be to multiplex the emitter LEDs, lighting one at a time, and have only a small number of light sensors.

If light is blocked between one LED and the sensor, you know something's there. It's easier to multiplex LEDs in an on/off manner than to multiplex low level analog signals for acquisition.

However, I'm not sure this is the right way to detect the position of your object. You'd need to share more info.

Comment: I really like your idea of lighting the LEDs on a strip one at a time. However, I could imagine that reducing the receivers on the other side could lead to alignment or capturing problems. But choosing the right components (viewing angle, luminous intensity, sensitivity, amp) could lead to good results.

Answer (score 3):

An single LED, or multiple LEDs connected in series can be used as a photodetector. The output needs to be suitably amplified.

However, a commercial LED strip cannot (usually) be used as a photodetector (without modification) because a commerical LED strip generally contains other components which will interfere with such use. The same applies to devices get commonly called "LEDs" which are more than a single light emitting diode. If they contain extra circuitry, their use as a photodetector will probably be problematic.

One way to tell if something called an LED is simply a light emitting diode, or whether it contains extra circuitry, is whether it requires an external resistor to prevent over current, when attached to a voltage source. That is, if you can directly connect the device to, say a 5V source, then it is NOT simply an LED, even if it is advertised as such. Similarly, if you can connect a strip to some voltage source, without a current limit resistor, it is probably not suitable.

If you have a high impedance volt-meter, you can always test your LED or LED strip, by shining light at the LEDs (unplugged of course) and seeing if you can measure any voltage across the terminals. If you read a voltage, then you can conclude that you can use it for a photo-detector. However, if you don't read a voltage, and your meter can be set to read micro-amps, try that. However, even if you cannot get a reading either way, that doesn't completely rule out the possibility of using the LED as a photo-detector. As I said, the output of a LED used as a photo-detector needs to be amplified.

Comment: I like your practical suggestion to simply do some measurements. Any idea why there are no photodiode strips out there?

Answer (score 0):

In most LED strips the LEDs are in series with a resistor, multiple of such circuits are then in parallel across the strip's power lines. In order to determine the object's position, you'd need to know which LED(s) receives less light, so you would need individual connections to each LED.

So that means you need to completely disassemble the strip. In my view that makes it very impractical to use a LED strip as the detector. It will be much easier to use individual light sensors.

**So** yes you can but it will be very impractical and not worth the trouble.

Also LEDs are not designed to detect light, they can be used that way but have very low sensitivity so you will need sensitive electronics to get a usable signal. Using LDRs or photodiodes is a much simpler solution as these are much more sensitive so there's no delicate amplifier needed.

Comment: I see. My idea was to use pre-manufactured strips, because of ease of installation and perfect alignment between the opposing strips. To my knowledgs LEDs are quite sensitive to their own emitted wavelenght, so I thought this could suffice for relatively small distances. Are there any obvious reasons why photodiode strips would be a bad idea? I did google a lot, but without success.